# node.js - Calling external API and saving it's response to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, post

The code below lets me easily access a movie from external database.
As a response i am getting all data about the movie i select by specifying the 't' (title) in the qs: of request.

```
    .get(function(req,res,next){
            request({
                uri: ' http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=7776cbde',
                qs: {
                    api_key: '7776cbde',
                    t: 'Star Wars'
                }
            }).pipe(res);
        });
```

I would like to create similar POST request that will fetch the data from external API and save it to local mongoDB database. The request will only be a movie title and based on the title i need to fetch all the remaining data about the movie into my local db.

I have used code below to create a movie in my db based on request body and it worked fine

```
 .post(function(req,res){        
        var movie = new Movie(req.body);
        //this will save our movie in application database
        movie.save()
        res.status(201).send(movie);
        })
```

But I can't quite do it fetching the data from external API:

```
.post(function(req,res,next){
            var params = req.body.params;
            request({
                uri: ' http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=7776cbde',
                qs: {
                    api_key: '7776cbde',
                }
            }).pipe(res);
        })
```

this is as close i get and as reply i can see a json formatted movie, but what is saved is merely some scraps of information.

Comment: 1. please post a minimal working example
2. what exactly do you get from your node.js express app when you send a POST to it? I have made the same POST request as you have - `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=7776cbde` and I get a 40 lines json with details about `Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2`
3. you dont have any `movie.save()` in your last piece of code, so nothing will be saved to your data base.